# pandas grabbing value to fill in new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get new columns B and C with a condition B value will be positive if the ‘A’ of one day is bigger than the ‘A’ of the day before. Otherwise, the value will be negative (C column).

Here is an example of what I am trying to get:

```
    A         B         C
0.  167765   
1.  235353    235353
2.   89260     89260
3.  188382    188382
4.  104677              104677
5.  207723              207723
```

I notice that this will cause an index error because the number of data in column B and C will be different from the original column A.

Currently, I am doing via this to test move specific data to column B and this cause **length of values does not match the length of index** error:

```
df['B'] = np.where(df['A'] <= 250000)
```

how do I accomplish the desired output where the first row is NA or empty?

**desired output**:

```
    B          C
0.     
1.  235353
2.   89260
3.  188382
4.             104677
5.             207723
```

Comment: And for C, which data do you want to move ? Seems they are under 250000 too

Comment: Hi, Thank you, for your comment. For C I want to move only 104677 and 207723. Yes they are, but I am not so sure how to accomplish it

Comment: Hi, can you specify what's your input?

Comment: Hi @EliranAbdoo, could you please elaborate when you ask my input? I am not really sure what you mean by my input.

Comment: It is not clear whether the first segment of code in your question represents your input DataFrame, as you're saying "an example of what I am trying to get".

Comment: If your meaning is how to get the DataFrame presented in the third code segment, given the first one, then you probably just need to take df.loc[:, ['B', 'C']]. I'm not sure how the second segment relates to the task your'e referring to. As a side not, the function np.where takes a boolean ndarray (namely, mask), together with two ndarrays X and Y, and returns an ndarray which corresponds to X where the mask is True, and to Y otherwise. In your example you provided np.where with only the mask, which return the indices in which the condition is true and doesn't seem like your desired behavior.

Comment: @EliranAbdoo, hi, the first segment of my dataframe is just a straight forward multiplication to get A column (e.g. x. * y = A). The next task is to have dataframe like my output desire which is B and C column with a condition B value will be positive if the ‘A’ of one day is bigger than the ‘A’ of the day before. Otherwise, the value will be negative (C column) I will add more details in my question.

Comment: What you're looking for is pd.rolling. This is a way to aggregate values of a Pandas Series based on a windows size. Given `a`, a series of your A column values, `a.rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: x[1] - x[0])` will extract a series of the same length that contains the differences between consecutive days. From here you can use construct your desired output quite easily (e.g. using a>=0 as a mask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to understand how you got to your final result by the method you're describing

In my understanding a value should be placed in column B if it is greater than the value the day before. Otherwise in column C.

You may need to correct me or adapt this answer if you meant differently.

The trick is in to use `.where` on a pandas `Series` object, which inserts the `NaN`s automatically.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [167765, 235353, 89260, 188382, 104677, 207723]})

diffs = df['A'].diff()

df['B'] = df['A'].where(diffs >= 0)
df['C'] = df['A'].where(diffs < 0)
```

`diffs` is going to be the following `Series` which also comes with a handy `NaN` in the first row.

```
0         NaN
1     67588.0
2   -146093.0
3     99122.0
4    -83705.0
5    103046.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comparing with `NaN` always returns `False`. Therefore we can omit the first row by comparing for the positive and the negative seperately.

The resulting table looks like this

```
        A         B         C
0  167765       NaN       NaN
1  235353  235353.0       NaN
2   89260       NaN   89260.0
3  188382  188382.0       NaN
4  104677       NaN  104677.0
5  207723  207723.0       NaN
```

Comment: Hi, your answer is half corrent BUT your approach has give me an idea how to solve my issues. So, thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

You can try giving explicit list of index:

```
df['B'] = np.where(df.index.isin([1, 2, 3]), df['A'], np.nan)
df['C'] = np.where(df.index.isin([4, 5]), df['A'], np.nan)
```